# Solving ODE knowing general solution of a linear ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following ODE.

$$ f''(x) + p(x)f'(x) + q(x)f(x) = 0 $$

Assume that it has general solution $f(x) = c_1 f_1(x) + c_2 f_2(x)$. Now, consider the following ODE.

$$ g'''(x) + g'(x)(-2p'(x)-p^2(x)+4q(x)) + g(x)(-p''(x)-p(x)p'(x)+2q'(x)) = 0 $$

The claim is that it is possible to obtain solution of $g(x)$ in terms of $f_1$ and $f_2$. It is not clear to me how. The only thing that I have noticed (not clear if useful) that ODE can be rewritten in the following way.

$$ g'''(x) -2g'(x)(p'(x)+\frac{p^2}{2}(x)-2q(x)) -g(x)(p'+\frac{p^2}{2}-2q)'(x) = 0 $$

It looks very close to the product rule but not quite as there is factor of $2$ difference between terms.

I found that solution is supposed to be the following which maybe can help to guess how to find this solution.

$$ g(x) = e^{\int p(x) dx} \left( c_1 f_1^2(x) + c_2 f_1(x)f_2(x) + c_3 f_2^2(x) \right)$$

I considered a new function $h(x) = g(x) e^{-\int p(x) dx}$ and found a differential equation that it satisfies.

$$h'''+3ph''+(p'+2p^2+4q)h'+(2q'+4pq)h = 0$$

It is not clear to me how this weight factor $e^{-\int p(x) dx}$ is motivated because the resulting differential equation is still not obvious to me on how to solve it.